# Scheduler Quartz start but not it's running more time

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat6, quartz-scheduler

In my web-app (Tomcat 6) I define a Quartz Scheduler in a class *extending HttpServlet*: this class is called to init.

The scheduler runs immediately and it has an interval of 1 minute, but after the first step it's not running.

When I change the parameter of scheduler by webpage, the scheduler is running correctly with the same code.

This is the code:

```
JobDetail job = newJob(ClassOfTask.class).withIdentity(NAME_JOB_MAIL, NAME_JOB_THREAD).build();
//various code
String cronExpression = buildCronExpression();
Trigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity(NAME_TRIGGER).startAt(startJob).endAt(endJob).forJob(job.getKey()).withSchedule(cronSchedule(cronExpression)).build();
scheduler.addJob(jobDetail, true);
scheduler.scheduleJob(trigger);
```

I tried to insert

```
scheduler.start();
```

but the problem remains.

When I modify the scheduled task in web page, I use this method

```
scheduler.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.getKey(), trigger);
```

and in this case it works.

What's it the problem?

Comment: How do you create the Scheduler in your App ? Is it application-scoped ?